# Realm : Invalid format of Realm file

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm using `realm` for `databse processing`in my `android project`.
And I got some user's report about the `crash`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: Invalid format of Realm file.
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions()(SourceFile:-2)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.&lt;init&gt;()(SourceFile:64)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.&lt;init&gt;()(SourceFile:49)
at io.realm.BaseRealm.&lt;init&gt;()(SourceFile:77)
at io.realm.Realm.&lt;init&gt;()(SourceFile:138)
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate()(SourceFile:269)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance()(SourceFile:249)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache()(SourceFile:114)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance()(SourceFile:213)
```

I never face the crash while developing but seems that my user got it many times.
Below is my implementation which crash was detected:

```
private Realm getRealmFromConfig(Context context) {
    RealmConfiguration config = getRealmConfigByDBName(context, databaseName);
    Realm.compactRealm(config);
    return Realm.getInstance(config);
}

public RealmConfiguration getRealmConfigByDBName(Context context, String dbName) {
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .name(dbName)
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .setModules(new Module())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    return config;
}
```

The crash log points out that crash occur in line `return Realm.getInstance(config);`

I have a look at Realm.java file but still can not get any more information which related to message `Invalid format of Realm file`.
So any one can help to give me a solution or workaround which can resolve the problem or some theory about why crash occurs.

Many thanks!

Comment: I am a Realm developer. Please file this at github as it sounds like a potential bug in `Realm.compactRealm()`.

Comment: Yes, @geisshirt, I found a topic here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2746 but his solution was not working for me :(. So this bug will be fixed by next release or should I have to do some tricks?

Comment: If you can get hold on the invalid file, we would be very happy if you can send us it.

Comment: as I said above, I did not face this problem while developing but my user got it. So it's hard for me to get the invalid file. Anyway if I face it, I'll send you :)

Comment: in advance thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I downgraded Realm from **2.0.0 to 1.0.1** (2.0.0 has a serious bug).

The way I solved it was not clever (not even close) but it's the fastest. I caught the ***IllegalArgumentException*** and then delete the Realm database file.
¯_(ツ)_/¯